# Use information from objects in a child form from a main form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a C# form called Form1.cs. By pressing a button, a new Form called Form2.cs comes up and I do something in form2. I have some variables in both forms.

I want to communicate between these two forms like this.

in form1:

```
string s=frm2.textbox1.text;`
```

**form2:**

```
if(frm1.checkbox1.checked==true)
```

or something like these codes.
I have tried the below code:

**form1:**

```
Form2 f=new Form2(this);
f.showDialog();`
```

**form2:**

```
private Form1 mainForm = null;
public Form2(Form callingForm)
{
    mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
`
```

and this works. But I don't want to use pointers like "this" and call this.mainform. Is there another way to communicate between forms like function calls?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass forms like this?

Comment: I just want to try better ways.

Comment: Why do you think there are better ways? What is it about passing references that you want to improve?

Comment: Passing references increases coupling and limits reuseability, which may or may not be an issue depending on the particular circumstances.  It also makes testing more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of different approaches you can take that remove the need for Form 2 to know about Form 1 and that will make Form 2 reusable:

## Delegates

You can declare a delegate function on the second form, and then pass a delegate method from the first form to the second one, so the second form can call back to the first one.

That approach means your second form no longer has any direct knowledge of your first form.  It also means you can reuse the second form from any form and just pass in a delegate with the correct signature. Example below:

#### Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f=new Form2(UpdateTextBox);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox(string newText)
    {
        label1.Text = newText;
    }
}
```

#### Form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void ChoiceMadeOnForm2Delegate(string choice);

    private ChoiceMadeOnForm2Delegate _choiceDelegate;

    public Form2(ChoiceMadeOnForm2Delegate choiceDelegate)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _choiceDelegate = choiceDelegate;
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _choiceDelegate(textBox1.Text);
        Close();
    }
}
```

In this example the delegate method just has one parameter, but if you want to pass back a series of values to Form 1 your delegate method declaration could include more parameters, or the parameter could be a class instead.

If you also want to set initial values for Form2 from Form 1 you can of course add those as constructor parameters for Form 2 and pass them in when you new up Form 2.

In your example Form 2 is shown as a dialog, but if you ever want to not show Form 2 modally you could even have a delegate on Form 1 that you pass to Form 2, so the forms can then communicate in two directions.

## Use data binding and a shared class

Another approach is to use databinding, whereby you bind both forms to the same object and pass that object from Form 1 to Form 2 in its constructor when you open Form 2.  When either form then changes the object those changes will then be reflected on both forms simultaneously and instantly.

To do that you need to read up on a concept called databinding and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the data class.  You then bind the relevant controls on both forms to that class.  Documentation on `INotifyPropertyChanged` can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank You very much. It worked. (I mean the first approach).

Comment: Very complicated solution. Specially for class/Form which take `bool` parameter and return `string`. Beside OP didn't want to pass reference of `Form1` to `Form2`. But delegate do it, check `_choiceDelegate.Target` property. More - delegates will cause a memory leak if you not dispose them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only information that `Form2` needs and expose only information that `Form1` needs

Form1

```
string valueOfForm2 = null;
using Form2 f = new Form2(this.checkbox1.Checked)
{
    f.ShowDialog();
    valueOfForm2 = f.ReturnValue;
}
```

Then use `valueOfForm2` for you needs in the Form1

Form2

```
bool _IsForm1ValueChecked;

//By this property text will be exposed to outside of Form
public string ReturnValue { get { return this.textbox1.Text;} }

public Form2(bool isForm1ValueChecked)
{
    _IsForm1ValueChecked = isForm1ValueChecked;
}
```

`_IsForm1ValueChecked` will be set in the contructor - then use it for your purpose in the Form2

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think for such stuff, I was using properties.
I prefer not access from one form the controls of the other one.
If I need information from one form, I prefer giving the access to this other form through properties. 
More than that, you can define an interface that will contain all the properties/methods that you need for the communication between the forms. It will be clearer to work with an interface, you will get the information you need and won't be overloaded with other irrelevant information.

For example:

```
Interface IForm2
{
   // your properties
   string PersonName {get;}     // Just an example

   // your methods
}

class Form1: Form
{
     private IForm2 _form2;

     void Foo()
     {
         var pname = _form2.PersonName;   // Just an example
     }
}

class Form2: Form, IForm2
{
    string PersonName 
    {
         get 
         {
              return personNameTextBox.Text;
         }
    }
}
```